# set RESTful setting of locale in Rails w/o scoping of resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, internationalization

Basically I have a static page in my app with a RESTful URL to the translated page.

i.e.

```
  https://foo.bar/ja
```

I don't or need to do any

```
      scope "/:locale" do
        resources :books
      end
```

maneuvers in my `routes.rb` file because it is simply a page of highlights in that particular locale, not a map of the whole translated site.

I understand that if I set my locale as a `param` then it would be as easy as doing:

```
def set_locale
 I18n.locale = params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
end
```

in my application controller. What would be the equivalent statement that I would make in my `ApplicationController` to grab the locale from the path instead of the param as in:

```
https://foo.bar/<locale-goes-here>
```

I tried looking at this: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html but couldn't find this special treatment of a RESTful solution, in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could do this:

```
def set_locale
 current_locale = 'en' # default one
 parsed_locale = request.fullpath.split('/').last
 parsed_locale = I18n.available_locales.map(&:to_s).include?(parsed_locale.to_s) ? parsed_locale : current_locale
 I18n.locale = parsed_locale
end
```